# Getting a Single Location Update in Android 2.2

Tags: android, location

The application I am developing requires a single location update for one specific operation, which is available in API level 9, except that I am required to target API level 8, where `LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate()` is not available.

How would I go about requesting a single update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Request multiple updates, via `requestLocationUpdates()`, then remove your request (via `removeUpdates()`) once you receive the first update, or when you no longer need the location (e.g., timeout in case no location data is available).